# SSRS and code 39 full ASCII doesn't display right

Tags: ssrs-2012

I just purchased idautomation fonts for code 39 full ascii. when i changed my text to IDAutomationYC39M, ssrs doesn't generate that as barcode and showed as plain text. any idea why this is? please advise. thank you all for your help

Comment: This is happening locally or on the server? Font is deployed on the server? Does it occur on the preview vs export as pdf?

Comment: it happens on the server itself. pdf, ie, chrome, all are like that. When you iin report builder design mode, you can see the font correctly but doesn't export right. the font is installed on the server and is working on notepad.